# How to make GNU make to rebuild phony target only when prerequisite changes?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my case I have `requirements` target, which installs needed Python packages and `test`, which runs tests and depends on previous one.

Installing dependencies is a long operation and I want it to be executed only when `requirements.txt` changes. How can I achieve that?

Here is a simplified example of Makefile, that I have now:

```
.PHONY: test requirements

requirements: requirements.txt
    pip install -r $<

test: tests/ | requirements
    py.test $^
```

Comment: Then why do you declare the requirements PHONY?

Comment: `make` just compare modification time, so you need some file for which possible to compare time between it (file) and `requirements.txt`

Comment: @Jens I've done that, because `requirements` target doesn't produce any files, so it's "phony". However I'm not an expert of GNU make, so I'm not sure if this logic is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @user1034749 pointed out, Make compares the modification times of files. If you want it to know when `requirements.txt` has been modified since the last installation, you must give it a file whose modification time is the same as the time of the last installation, so that it can compare the two. In other words, you must have a dummy file and modify it whenever you perform the installation. You can call it anything you like, but I will call it "installation":

```
.PHONY: test

installation: requirements.txt
    pip install -r $<
    touch $@

test: tests/ | installation
    py.test $^
```